How to access static local variable of function in parameter tree of Vector cast 6.3 for unit testing
I'm using vector cast 6.3 for my unit testing.
I'm using embedded 'C' programming language.
I have a function as below, I'm not able to cover the below 'if' statement condition.
As  static local variable "DataCntr" is not reflected under my parameter tree.
void ResetData (void)
{
  static int DataCntr = 0u;
  DataCntr++;
  if (DataCntr > 1000000u)
  {
      DataCntr = DataCntr;
  }
}

Need support/guidance is there a way/solution to make Static local variable reflected in parameter tree?
